# Determine extrinsic camera with opencv to opengl with world space object

Tags: opengl, opencv, camera-calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I'm using opencv and openframeworks (ie. opengl) to calculate a camera (world transform and projection matrixes) from an image (and later, several images for triangulation).

For the purposes of opencv, the "floor plan" becomes the object (ie. the chessboard) with 0,0,0 the center of the world.
The world/floor positions are known so I need to get the projection information (distortion coefficients, fov etc) and the extrinsic coordinates of the camera.

[image: 2D input coordinates]

I have mapped the view-positions of these floor-plan points onto my 2D image in normalised view-space ([0,0] is top-left. [1,1] is bottom right).

The Object (floor plan/world points) is on xz plane, -y up, so I convert to the xy plane (Not sure here if z-up is negative or positive...) for opencv as it needs to be planar

```
ofMatrix4x4 gWorldToCalibration(
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
    );
```

I pass 1,1 as the ImageSize to calibrateCamera.
flags are `CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO|V_CALIB_FIX_K4|CV_CALIB_FIX_K5`
`calibrateCamera` runs successfully, gives me a low-error (usually around `0.003`).

using `calibrationMatrixValues` I get a sensible FOV, usually around 50 degrees, so I'm pretty sure the intrinsic properties are correct.

Now to calculate the extrinsic world-space transform of the camera... I don't believe I need to use `solvePnP` as I only have one object (although I tried all this before with it and came back with the same results)

```
//  rot and trans output...
cv::Mat& RotationVector = ObjectRotations[0];
cv::Mat& TranslationVector = ObjectTranslations[0];

//  convert rotation to matrix
cv::Mat expandedRotationVector;
cv::Rodrigues(RotationVector, expandedRotationVector);

//  merge translation and rotation into a model-view matrix
cv::Mat Rt = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64FC1);
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
   for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) 
        Rt.at<double>(y, x) = expandedRotationVector.at<double>(y, x);
Rt.at<double>(0, 3) = TranslationVector.at<double>(0, 0);
Rt.at<double>(1, 3) = TranslationVector.at<double>(1, 0);
Rt.at<double>(2, 3) = TranslationVector.at<double>(2, 0);
Rt.at<double>(3, 3) = 1.0;
```

Now I've got a rotation & transform matrix, but it's column major (I believe as the object is totally skewed if I don't transpose, and the code above looks column major to me)

```
//  convert to openframeworks matrix AND transpose at the same time
ofMatrix4x4 ModelView;
for ( int r=0;  r<4;    r++ )
    for ( int c=0;  c<4;    c++ )
        ModelView(r,c) = Rt.at<double>( c, r );
```

Swap my planes back to my-coordinate space (y up) using the inverse of the matrix before.

```
//  swap y & z planes so y is up
ofMatrix4x4 gCalibrationToWorld = gWorldToCalibration.getInverse();
ModelView *= gCalibrationToWorld;
```

Not sure if I NEED to do this... I didn't negate the planes when I put them INTO the calibration...

```
//  invert y and z planes for -/+ differences between opencv and opengl
ofMatrix4x4 InvertHandednessMatrix(
    1,  0,  0, 0,
    0,  -1, 0, 0,
    0,  0,  -1, 0,
    0,  0,  0,  1
    );
ModelView *= InvertHandednessMatrix;
```

And finally, the model view is object-relative-to-camera and I want to invert it to be camera-relative-to-object(0,0,0)

```
ModelView = ModelView.getInverse();
```

[image: output 3D view]

This results in a camera in the wrong place, and rotated wrong. It's not *too* far off, the camera is the right side of the Y plane, the translation isn't wildly off, and I think it's the right way up.... just not correct yet.
The paint-drawn blue circle is where I expect the camera to be.

I've gone through loads of SO answers, the documentation a dozen times, but not quite found anything right, I'm pretty sure I've covered everything I need to space-conversion-wise, but maybe I've missed something obvious? 
Or doing something in the wrong order?

**Update 1 - world-space plane...**
I've changed my world-space floor plane to XY(Z up) to match the input for openCV. (gWorldToCalibration is now an identity matrix).
The rotation is still wrong, and the projection output is the same, but I think the translation is correct now (It's certainly on the correct side of the markers)
[image: 3D view on XY plane]

**Update2 - Real image size**
I'm playing with the image size going into the camera calibration; seeing as I'm using 1,1 which is normalised, but the imageSize parameter is in integers, I thought this might be significant... And I guess it is (The red box is where the projected view-space points intersect with z=0 floor plane)
Without any distortion correction, here is the result (Only thing changed is imagesize from 1,1 to 640,480. I multiply my normalised input-view-space coords by 640,480 too)
[image]
I'm going to try and add distortion correction to see if it lines up *perfectly*...

Comment: Are you sure that you visualize the camera position, but not translational component of extrinsic camera matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've mis-read your comment, but the final modelview matrix (which i believe is/should be the cam pos) is set to the ofCamera global transform. The visualisation is as follows; green +Y, blue +z, red +x.

Comment: The grid is cantered around 0,0,0. I may have gotten extrinsic and camera transform wrong? But that's what the invert is for.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the inversion step. Then this seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now at least I'm treating my Edit 2 (ImageSize must be something bigger than 1,1) as the fix as it produced results much, much more like what I was expecting.

I might have things upside down at the moment, but this is producing pretty good results.

Comment: hi! I have a similar problem but.. from the edits it's not very clear.. in the end what was you step-by-step procedure?

Comment: The solution to the problem was to NOT normalise my image coordinates, so instead of floats and imagesize 1,1 I used pixel coordinates and 1920,1080. I don't believe I needed to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is to verify that markers are reprojected correctly on the image given estimated intrinsic and extrinsic camera matrices. Then you can find camera position in the global frame and to see if it agrees with markers positions. (Use coordinate system as in OpenCV.) One this is done, there are not much things that can go wrong. Since you want points to lie on the xz plane, you need just a single transformation of coordinates. As I see, you do it with gWorldToCalibration matrix. Then apply the transformation both to markers and to camera position and verify that markers are in the right place. Then the camera position will be also correct (unless something went wrong with the handedness of coordinate system, but can be easily corrected).

Comment: The markers are reprojected from the camera into rays (the blue lines) which are obviously in the wrong place. The green polygon is the ray projection to N metres, and red is where I hits the y=0 plane (nonesense in this case). But I guess you mean re-projected into view/image space, I shall do that in the morning! And also maybe convert everything so z=up to remove one step...

Comment: Yes, I mean re-projection on the image, immediately after calibration. This can be done by multiplying intrinsic and extrinsic matrices obtained by coordinates of markers (in the coordinate system used for calibration).

Comment: My results aren't good... I make a 4x4 intrinsic matrix (0,0,0,1 for the additional col/row) and copy the rest from the cameraMatrix from calibrateCamera. I'm using `rT` as the extrinsic matrix (is this right?) and multiply by my normalised input-view-coordinates.
Each re-projected world-position is off by a similar amount...
(`4.0,1.7,5.5`, `4.3,1.6,6.0`, `4.7, 1.5, 6.0`, `4.8,1.6,5.5` )
My extrinsic translation is `1.4, 4.3, 6.3`. I can't help but think these values are linked.... am I doing the re-projection testing right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should **not** take the inverse of *gWorldToCalibration*

```
ofMatrix4x4 gCalibrationToWorld = gWorldToCalibration.getInverse();
```

Here I posted code, which is doing more or less what you want [OpenCV- to OpenGL COS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20373984/2631225). It's in C, but should be similar in C++.