# Camera displacement estimation in OpenCV - incorrect pose output

Tags: python, opencv, camera, position, translation

I am currently filming using one camera facing downwards with a chessboard pattern in a fixed position on the ground. I am using python with OpenCV to track the displacement of the camera and using the output to plot displacement in terms of the x,y,z directions. Ultimately I want to mount the camera to the underside of a hovering multirotor UAV in order to calibrate the GPS accuracy.

The basic method I am using is:

1. Define object points
2. Open video
3. Undistort frame based on saved camera matrix (camera calibration already performed)
4. Find chessboard corners
5. If corners found, refine corners
6. Find the rotation and translation vectors (cv2.pnpransac)
7. Project 3D points to image plane (cv2.projectpoints)
8. Convert rotation vector to rotation matrix as per [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515200/python-opencv-solvepnp-yields-wrong-translation-vector)

   ```
   np_rodrigues = np.asarray(rvecs_new[:,:],np.float64)
   rmatrix = cv2.Rodrigues(np_rodrigues)[0]
   ```
9. **Calculate camera pose as per [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265714/camera-pose-estimation-opencv-pnp)**

   ```
   cam_pos = -np.matrix(rmatrix).T * np.matrix(tvecs_new)
   ```
10. Store values

    ```
    camx.append(cam_pos.item(0))
    camy.append(cam_pos.item(1))
    camz.append(cam_pos.item(2))
    ```

**However** when I run this code with a video that should be a straight line at constant altitude, the plotted x,y graph gives a curved x,y plot, and z is not constant as shown by the x,z plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJoa4.jpg

**Is there any reason why this should not be giving a straigh line on the graph? Perhaps an error with camera pose calculation in step 9?**

---

The complete code is as follows:

```
    # Criteria, defining object points
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #IMPORTANT: Enter chess board dimensions 
    chw = 9
    chh = 6

    #Defining draw functions for lines
    def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
        corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
        cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
        cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
        cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
        return img

    # Load previously saved data
    with np.load('camera_calib.npz') as X:
        mtx, dist, _, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs','imgpts')]

    # Criteria, defining object points
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    objp = np.zeros((chh*chw,3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chw,0:chh].T.reshape(-1,2)

    # Setting axis
    axis = np.float32([[9,0,0], [0,6,0], [0,0,-10]]).reshape(-1,3)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Calibration\\video_chess2.MP4')
    count = 0
    fcount = 0
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret1, img = cap.read()
        if ret1 == False or count==lim:
            print('Video analysis complete.')
            break
        if count > 0:
            h,  w = img.shape[:2]
            newcameramtx, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx,dist,(w,h),1,(w,h))
            # Undistorting
            img2 = cv2.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)

            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ret2, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (chw,chh),None)
            if ret2 == True:
                fcount = fcount+1
                # Refining corners
                cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)

                # Find the rotation and translation vectors
                rvecs_new, tvecs_new, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners, mtx, dist)

                # Project 3D points to image plane
                imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs_new, tvecs_new, mtx, dist)
                draw(img2,corners,imgpts)
                cv2.imshow('img',img2)
                cv2.waitKey(1)


                # Converting rotation vector to rotation matrix
                np_rodrigues = np.asarray(rvecs_new[:,:],np.float64)
                rmatrix = cv2.Rodrigues(np_rodrigues)[0]

                # Pose (According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265714/camera-pose-estimation-opencv-pnp)
                cam_pos = -np.matrix(rmatrix).T * np.matrix(tvecs_new)

                camx.append(cam_pos.item(0))
                camy.append(cam_pos.item(1))
                camz.append(cam_pos.item(2))

            else:
                print 'Board not found'

        count += 1
        print count
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    plt.plot(camx,camy)
    plt.show()
```