# Matching a real world picture with a 3D model inaccuracy problem

Tags: python, opencv, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, hololens

Suppose that I have a fixed physical camera and static scene. I have a point cloud scan of the physical world, so I can use basic surfaces and cubes to perform a simple reconstruction of the real world.
[Simple reconstruction in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUBoJ.png)
[Pointcloud scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOWIk.png)

Next step is calculate real world camera pose using checkerboard and PnP. After calculation, I used the resulting Tvec, Rvec, and ProjectPoint to draw a virtual cube in world unit, it shows up perfectly, showing that the camera pose is valid within opencv framework.

[Verify camera pose after PnP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOkql.png)

However, when I put the resulting camera transformation in Unity, the camera translation seems to be off by half a meter compared to the physical world estimate. Ideally what I would like to achieve is a pixel-perfect alignment between a real world image and a unity camera view image (which is a digital twin of the physical world).

[Tvec Rvec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuCEi.png)

Thank you for your insights in advance!

Below is code for calculatePnP

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import os
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

# Used to draw standard axis
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html
def draw(img, corners, imgPoints):
    corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
    print("int(corner[0])):\n {0}".format(int(corner[0])))
    print("int(corner[1])):\n {0}".format(int(corner[1])))
    print("int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[0]):\n {0}".format(int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[0])))
    print("int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[1]):\n {0}".format(int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[1])))
    img = cv2.line(img, (int(corner[0]), int(corner[1])), (int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[0]),int(tuple(imgPoints[0].ravel())[1])), (255,0,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, (int(corner[0]), int(corner[1])), (int(tuple(imgPoints[1].ravel())[0]),int(tuple(imgPoints[1].ravel())[1])), (0,255,0), 5)
    img = cv2.line(img, (int(corner[0]), int(corner[1])), (int(tuple(imgPoints[2].ravel())[0]),int(tuple(imgPoints[2].ravel())[1])), (0,0,255), 5)
    return img

# used to draw a standard cube (1,1,1)
# opencv official
def drawCube(img, corners, imgpts):
    imgpts = np.int32(imgpts).reshape(-1,2)
    # draw ground floor in green
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[:4]],-1,(0,255,0),-3)
    # draw pillars in blue color
    for i,j in zip(range(4),range(4,8)):
        img = cv2.line(img, tuple(imgpts[i]), tuple(imgpts[j]),(255),3)
    # draw top layer in red color
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[4:]],-1,(0,0,255),3)
    return img

# Load the camera calibration data
os.chdir('C:/Users/')
with np.load('opencvcalib.npz') as calibData:
    mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = [calibData[i] for i in ('mtx', 'dist', 'rvecs', 'tvecs')]

print("Previously calibrated dist:\n {0}".format(dist))
print("mtx:\n {0}".format(mtx))
# Define the chess board rows and columns
rows = 9
cols = 6

# Set the termination criteria for the corner sub-pixel algorithm
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 30, 0.001)

# Prepare the object points: (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0), ..., (6,5,0). They are the same for all images
objectPoints = np.zeros((rows * cols,3), np.float32)
objectPoints[:,  :2] = np.mgrid[0:rows, 0:cols].T.reshape(-1, 2)
print("objpts before divide:\n {0}".format(objectPoints))
#scale object points to real world, 1unit = 0.034m, should divide by 29.41176470588235
objectPoints = objectPoints / 29.41176470588235
print("divided objpts:\n {0}".format(objectPoints))

# Create the axis points, unit is meters, here shortest X axis is 10cm.
axisPoints = np.float32([[0.1, 0, 0], [0, 0.2, 0], [0, 0, -0.3]]).reshape(-1, 3)
#this unit is per checkerboard square
#axisPoints = np.float32([[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, -5]]).reshape(-1, 3)

# Loop over the image files
os.chdir('C:/Users/Calibration/extrinsics')
img = cv2.imread("ext3.jpg");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find the chess board corners, and visualize
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (rows, cols), None)
imgchkbrd = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners, ret)

cv2.imwrite('corners.jpg', imgchkbrd)


# Make sure the chess board pattern was found in the image
if ret == True:
    # Refine the corner position
    corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)

    # Find the rotation and translation vectors
    val, rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objectPoints, corners, mtx, dist)
    #success, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.solvePnP(objectPoints, corners, mtx, dist,flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
    #print("objpts:\n {0}".format(objectPoints))
    print("corners:\n {0}".format(corners))
    print ("Rotation Vector:\n {0}".format(rvecs))
    print ("Translation Vector:\n {0}".format(tvecs))

    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265714/camera-pose-estimation-opencv-pnp
    Rt = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)
    print ("Rt tuple:\n {0}".format(Rt))
    R = Rt.transpose()# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'transpose'
    pos = -R * tvecs #pos is the position of the camera expressed in the global frame
    roll = atan2(-R[2][1], R[2][2])
    pitch = asin(R[2][0])
    yaw = atan2(-R[1][0], R[0][0])
    print ("pos of camera:\n {0}".format(pos))
    #position of camera would be {- transpose( r ) * t }

    #quaternion
    r = Rotation.from_rotvec(rvecs.T)
    quaternion = r.as_quat()
    print("Quaternion1:\n {0}".format(quaternion))
 RotationMatrix,_ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvecs)
    print("RotationMatrix:\n {0}".format(RotationMatrix))

    # Project the 3D axis points to the image plane
    axisImgPoints, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axisPoints, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
        
        # Draw the axis lines
    img = draw(img, corners, axisImgPoints)

    #render a cube
    CubeAxis = np.float32([[0,0,0], [0,0.034,0], [0.034,0.034,0], [0.034,0,0],
                   [0,0,-0.034],[0,0.034,-0.034],[0.034,0.034,-0.034],[0.034,0,-0.034] ])
    axisImgPoints, jac = cv2.projectPoints(CubeAxis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
    img2 = drawCube(img, corners, axisImgPoints)
    
    # Display the image
    cv2.imshow('chess board', img2)
    cv2.imwrite('checkerboardpnp3.png', img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: mixup of rvec and tvec? position your camera you have some expectation of the values. don't just place it crooked. -- remember, unity is left-handed, opencv is right-handed