# How to place object in video with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Ok so I've used a chessboard image to calibrate my camera. This calibrates both the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the scene. Now I want to draw an object to sit on the table in which I had placed the chessboard. My question is do need the rotation+translation vectors of the camera to do this? And if so how can I get these after doing the calibration? Or are these vectors taken into account in the calibrateCamera function?

Basically after I calibrate the camera how can I now draw into the scene on top of a surface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `calibrateCamera` function provides you with the extrinsic (rotation+translation) and intrinsic (camera matrix K and distortion coefficients).

This allows you to project 3D points, expressed in the coordinate system of your chessboard, into an image acquired by the camera, for example using the `projectPoints` function ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints)). Using this approach, you can draw wireframe objects directly into the image by projecting the 3D edges using the `projectPoints` function.

If you would like to *render* more complex objects (i.e. including textures, etc), this requires using an auxiliary rendering engine since OpenCV does not provide such functionalities. You will have to use a rendering engine, say OpenGL, provide the projection details to it, retrieve the object rendered from the camera viewpoint in a buffer, and  overlay this buffer on top of your initial image.

However, notice that the result of this, which is called augmented-reality, may look weird sometimes, because it does not take into account the occlusions between your rendered object and the scene observed in the image... Handling occlusions appropriately would require a 3D model of the scene.

Answer (score 0):

[AldourDisciple post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192565/433685) is a great answer.

If I can add my 2 cents, this is a problem I worked with, and it is the basic problem of Augmented Reality, and more generally on how to integrate OpenCV and OpenGL (because you'll gonna use OpenGL to draw the 3d stuffs and use a OpenGL texture to show the underline OpenCV images from the video). You can find some (imho) good links, documentation and tutorial and references in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997021/augmented-reality-openglopencv/21999980#21999980) on that.