# Using OpenCV solvePnP for Augmented Reality in OpenGL

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es

I'm trying to build an Augmented Reality application in Android using [BoofCV](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (OpenCV alternative for Java) and OpenGL ES 2.0. I have a marker which I can get the image points of and "world to cam" transformation using BoofCV's solvePnP function. I want to be able to draw the marker in 3D using OpenGL. Here's what I have so far:

On every frame of the camera, I call `solvePnP`

```
Se3_F64 worldToCam = MathUtils.worldToCam(__qrWorldPoints, imagePoints);
mGLAssetSurfaceView.setWorldToCam(worldToCam);
```

This is what I have defined as the world points

```
static float qrSideLength = 79.365f; // mm

private static final double[][] __qrWorldPoints = {
        {qrSideLength * -0.5, qrSideLength * 0.5, 0},
        {qrSideLength * -0.5, qrSideLength * -0.5, 0},
        {qrSideLength * 0.5, qrSideLength * -0.5, 0},
        {qrSideLength * 0.5, qrSideLength * 0.5, 0}
};
```

I'm feeding it a square that has origin at its center, with a sidelength in millimeters.

I can confirm that the rotation vector and translation vector I'm getting back from `solvePnP` are reasonable, so I don't know if there's a problem here.

I pass the result from solvePnP into my renderer

```
public void setWorldToCam(Se3_F64 worldToCam) {

    DenseMatrix64F _R = worldToCam.R;
    Vector3D_F64 _T = worldToCam.T;

    // Concatenating the the rotation and translation vector into
    // a View matrix
    double[][] __view = {
        {_R.get(0, 0), _R.get(0, 1), _R.get(0, 2), _T.getX()},
        {_R.get(1, 0), _R.get(1, 1), _R.get(1, 2), _T.getY()},
        {_R.get(2, 0), _R.get(2, 1), _R.get(2, 2), _T.getZ()},
            {0, 0, 0, 1}
    };

    DenseMatrix64F _view = new DenseMatrix64F(__view);

    // Matrix to convert from BoofCV (OpenCV) coordinate system to OpenGL coordinate system
    double[][] __cv_to_gl = {
            {1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, -1, 0, 0},
            {0, -1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1}
    };

    DenseMatrix64F _cv_to_gl = new DenseMatrix64F(__cv_to_gl);

    // Multiply the View Matrix by the BoofCV to OpenGL matrix to apply the coordinate transform
    DenseMatrix64F view = new SimpleMatrix(__view).mult(new SimpleMatrix(__cv_to_gl)).getMatrix();

    // BoofCV stores matrices in row major order, but OpenGL likes column major order
    // I transpose the view matrix and get a flattened list of 16,
    // Then I convert them to floating point
    double[] viewd = new SimpleMatrix(view).transpose().getMatrix().getData();

    for (int i = 0; i < mViewMatrix.length; i++) {
        mViewMatrix[i] = (float) viewd[i];
    }
}
```

I'm also using the camera intrinsics I get from camera calibration to feed into the projection matrix of OpenGL

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method

    double fx = MathUtils.fx;
    double fy = MathUtils.fy;
    float fovy = (float) (2 * Math.atan(0.5 * height / fy) * 180 / Math.PI);
    float aspect = (float) ((width * fy) / (height * fx));

    // be careful with this, it could explain why you don't see certain objects
    float near = 0.1f;
    float far = 100.0f;

    Matrix.perspectiveM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, fovy, aspect, near, far);

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}
```

The square I'm drawing is the one defined in this [Google example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/OpenGL/HelloOpenGLES20/src/com/example/android/opengl/Square.java).

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

    // redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    // Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be the first* in order
    // for matrix multiplication product to be correct

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Draw shape
    mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);
}
```

I believe the problem has to do with the fact that this definition of a square in Google's example code doesn't take the real world side length into account. I understand that the OpenGL coordinate system has the corners (-1, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1) which doesn't correspond to the millimeter object points I have defined for use in BoofCV, even though they are in the right order.

```
static float squareCoords[] = {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right
```

Comment: Has no one done this before?

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I'm trying something similar to what you are doing here. Were you able to solve your problem? Also, do you have source code you can share?

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall the solution to this question nor do I still have access to the code base :(