# How to make OpenGL draw on detected markers?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl, augmented-reality

I am trying to develop a marker-based AR app on QT with OpenCV (4.1), OpenGL and C++. I can successfully detect and track the Aruco markers, and I can draw a cube on them with OpenCV. However, I want to render more complex images on them, like objects exported from Blender. Hence, I need OpenGL to do that and I don't want to use another extra library. My problem is, I don't know how to tell OpenGL "Hey, render this image on a marker, not anywhere else". Unfortunately, I couldn't find any proper documentation about how to do this. Can anyone at least point me in the right direction? My all Google searches are literally purple and I am stuck so bad. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Augmented Reality OpenGL+OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997021/augmented-reality-openglopencv)